# nrwl create shared module between libraries

Tags: angular, nrwl

I created a `nrwl` workspace with some apps and libraries. This libraries should share of common resources. I added this to a Shared module. The problem is that my linting is failing. I get the following error message:

> The 'libs/shared/services/svg.service.ts' file doesn't belong to any project.
>   The 'libs/shared/shared.module.ts' file doesn't belong to any project.

I added then the following to my `angular.json`

```
"shared": {
  "root": "libs/shared",
  "projectType": "library"
}
```

I think this is wrong, because **Shared** is actually not a library.

Any idea on how to share common resources between libraries?

Comment: Follow up: https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/653#issuecomment-412181139

Answer (score -3):

With reference to the error details provided.
Main reason for this error is this service is not included in the Shared module as provider.